# Извлечение даты и времени из строки Python

Tags: python-3.x, дата, datetime

Есть строка вида:

```
'Result: Timestamp;Value;Quality;Annotation26.10.2020 17:29:15.854;123;0;26.10.2020 17:29:20.556;321;0;; Error: None'
```

Как из нее извлечь дату в формате D/M/Y и время H/M/S?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант для конкретно этой строки

```
st = 'Result: Timestamp;Value;Quality;Annotation26.10.2020 17:29:15.854;123;0;26.10.2020 17:29:20.556;321;0;; Error: None'  
st.split(';')[3][10:]

import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime(st.split(';')[3][10:-4], '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Спасибо, все удалось.

Comment: @Petizzen можете поставить решение задачи :)